# Why HttpListener Start method Dispose stuff on exception ?

Tags: c#, .net, httplistener

There is something that I really don't understand with the HttpListener.

The code below speaks for itself and expose the "issue" in one way.

I simply instantiate two different HttpListener with the same single prefix for each one.
I then start the first listener, and of course I get an HttpListenerException when I try to start the second one (same prefix) .. so far so good.

Ok my fault (or the end user fault if we are going through a configuration tool). No panic, I will just clear the prefix of the second listener and specify a new one ... or stop the first listener and try to restart the second one, or whatever ...

But can't do all of this because as soon as I am trying to access the second listener Prefixes or anything else, I get an ObjectDisposedException (Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'System.Net.HttpListener').

My question is WHY ?
I do not see anything in HttpListener documentation specifying that on a HttpListenerException some inner stuff of HttpListener object is somehow disposed and the object is just useless from that point on ...

So this means that if I am starting an HttpListener and get an HttpListenerException I have to recreate a whole new HttpListener object in any case ? Seems a little bit weird for me (but there may be another way or a very good reason).

Thanks in advance for your answers !!

```
var listener1 = new HttpListener();
listener1.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/MyHandler/");
listener1.Start();

var listener2 = new HttpListener();
listener2.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/MyHandler/");

try
{
   listener2.Start();
}
catch (HttpListenerException ex)
{
  listener2.Prefixes.Clear(); // BAM ! ObjectDisposedException
}
```

Comment: @dlev: dude, do I have to follow you around all day telling you to put your comments as answers? How did you get an 18K rep? :)

Comment: @MusiGenesis Very well. I shall once again heed your advice :) My first instinct these days is to post one-off thoughts like that as comments, since I usually prefer to flesh out actual answers (unless the actual answer is literally a one-liner.) That being said, I may have swung too far in that direction. Good thing you're around!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exception means something has gone horribly wrong. Rather than allow unsuspecting consumers to continue to use a possibly corrupt and unstable object, it instead disposes of itself. Just create the new listener, and be happy that you don't have to worry about using a possibly useless object.

Comment: I somehow agree. But seriously ... I understand the HttpListener can't start because one of the prefix is already in use, but for me it doesn't justify to dispose it in this specific context (this is not an horribly wrong issue).
Indeed the HttpListener didn't even Started, so it is just an initialized raw object doing nothing ! 
So maybe the problem is more on the design of this HttpListener (I'll just decompile it and check the code by myself to see if there is a VERY GOOD reason to dispose it in that context ... maybe I am missing something).

Comment: @user1188511 If you look at the code, you'll see that if *anything* goes wrong during `Start()`, then it puts itself into a closed state, and then refuses to do anything further. You'll note that it catches `Exception`, rather than more specific exceptions, and it's for that reason that disallowing further use is the path taken. In theory, it could be improved to first catch known, recoverable exceptions, though I doubt that's high priority for the BCL team.

Comment: Yep just noticed the same.
Object is not really Disposed but Closed so returning a HttpListenerClosedException would make more sense (Dispose leads to confusion, nothing is really Disposed). Especially considering the fact that there is a Close method on HttpListener documented as "After calling this method,you can no longer use the HttpListener object". So definitely the exception should have been better named for coherence (and the HttpListener not closed on any Exception, even very easily recoverable cases).

Anyway thanks for your answer, rather a discussion than an answer I must admit ;)