# its possible in C# show image from html tag in form?

Tags: c#, html

i have problem when i want to show image from html tag in C# form. The image: 
[image: image from <img> tag]

So its possible guys to call image from html tag? 
please help me. Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can Render your HTML in WebBrowser control.

[**Show Dynamic HTML in WinForm Applications**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/101403/Show-Dynamic-HTML-in-WinForm-Applications)

The `WebBrowser control` is a well-known component which you can use to embed Internet Explorer into your `WinForm applications`

Comment: when i implement these example, in imported library 'using embeddedProtocol' got error.why?can you give me advice?

Comment: @Emil, i tried the example, and it works fine on me. just edit the url

Comment: when i clicked HttpListenerTest button in example available, i got error message , it said "HttpListenerException was un handled" reference to line " var ctx = srv.EndGetContext(ar);". Why?

Comment: see this for the reason of that error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11164969/4273446

Comment: ok bro, but why when i impelent to other project, that 'using EmbededProtocol;' got error message?
the error message is:
'EmbededProtocol' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you should add the `EmbededProtocol.DLL` as reference. you can find the DLL on the folder of embedProtocol.

Comment: ok its solved thanks!, but why when im changed url to "http://localhost/", i got Access Denied message?

Comment: can you give me advice?

Comment: I have found alternative ways using Navigate, etc: webBrowser1.Navigate("http://localhost/moodle/file.php/10/book.png");